# Not expected building results

Tags: prolog

I have a little question about my code : (it can be interpreted as a grid for example)

```
free(1,1).
free(1,3).
free(2,3).
free(2,1).
free(1,5).
free(5,6).
free(5,2).
free(5,4).

busy(5,1,white,pion).
busy(1,2,black,pion).
busy(1,4,black,pion).
busy(1,6,black,pion).
busy(5,3,white,pion).
busy(5,5,white,pion).

%all clauses for  move/6

move(X,Y, X2,Y2,white,pion) :-
   busy(X,Y,white,pion), free(X2,Y2), X2=X-1, Y2=Y-1.
move(X,Y, X2,Y2,white,pion) :-
   busy(X,Y,white,pion), free(X2,Y2), X2=X-1, Y2=Y+1.
move(X,Y, X2,Y2,black,pion) :-
   busy(X,Y,black,pion), free(X2,Y2), X2=X+1, Y2=Y-1.
move(X,Y, X2,Y2,black,pion) :-
   busy(X,Y,black,pion), free(X2,Y2), X2=X+1, Y2=Y+1.
```

When I execute this :

```
move(1,2,X,Y,black,pion).
```

in SWI-Prolog it says : false. whereas it should says true and return two statements :

- X2 =2 , Y2= 1
- X2=2, Y2=3

I do not understand why it doesn't work, could you please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

It is simply because you use `=` ("make sure that left-hand-side and right hand side unify") instead of `is/2` (evaluate the arithmetic expression on the right-hand side and unify with the left-hand-side) or even better `#=` (constrain the arithmetic values to be the same, even if not all the variables can be resolved yet), here:

```
X2=X-1, Y2=Y-1.
```

This unifies `X2` with the actual structure `-(X,1)`. Which will fail, as `X2` will be a value.

Use:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).  % for #= predicate
```

```
move(X,Y, X2,Y2,white,pion) :-
   busy(X,Y,white,pion), free(X2,Y2), X2 #= X-1, Y2 #= Y-1.
```

Also, move the test forwards:

```
move(X,Y, X2,Y2,white,pion) :-
   busy(X,Y,white,pion), X2 #= X-1, Y2 #= Y-1, free(X2,Y2).
```